# How to use Android Service or ServiceIntent

Tags: android, multithreading

Can someone help me understand how to use Android Service or IntentService correctly.  The documentation seems to contradict itself here:

```
    Caution: A service runs in the same process as the application in which it is 
declared and in the main thread of that application by default. If your service 
performs intensive or blocking operations while the user interacts with an 
activity from the same application, the service slows down activity performance. 
To avoid impacting application performance, start a new thread inside the service.
```

and here

```
public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  /**
   * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
   * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
   */
  public HelloIntentService() {
      super("HelloIntentService");
  }

  /**
   * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
   * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
   * stops the service, as appropriate.
   */
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
  }
}
```

Given the whole purpose of the Service or ServiceIntent is to run long running jobs in the background without affecting the UI why then does the example code do exactly what the Caution indicated you should not do - and I am assuming a call to Thread.sleep() will cause the main thread to block.

Am I correct in the following understanding:

1. The service itself still runs on the main application thread but has no UI component (Activity) and will continue running even if the application is not used by the user, unlike an Activity which will not

   2. Any long running background work must still create a separate thread to avoid blocking the main application thread
   3. AsyncTask is associated with an Activity which presumably will stop running if the application is no longer the active application (i.e. if the user switches to another application) which is why one would use Service or ServiceIntent if the task needs to keep running.
   4. IntentService will run the task on a separate thread to the main thread so there is no need to worry about blocking the main thread with long tasks or when calling Thread.sleep().

Have I misunderstood something with the description of Android Service or ServiceIntents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first comment is from the the documentation about services *in general*.

There is nothing in Android named `ServiceIntent`. Your code snippet is an `IntentService`.

In Java, we have classes and inheritance. `Service` is the base class from which all services inherit. `IntentService` extends `Service`.

If you call `startService()`, pointing to a class of yours that inherits directly from `Service`, you need to implement a background thread yourself, as `Service` will not do that for you.

If, however, you call `startService()`, pointing to a class of yours that inherits from `IntentService`, then you *will* get a background thread created for you automatically by `IntentService`. This is code added by `IntentService`, above and beyond what `Service` provides.

> and I am assuming a call to Thread.sleep() will cause the main thread to block.

No, because `onHandleIntent()` is called on the `IntentService`-supplied background thread.

> The service itself still runs on the main application thread

No. In Java, objects do not run on threads. Methods run on threads.

> Any long running background work must still create a separate thread to avoid blocking the main application thread

Any long-running background work needs to be performed on a background thread. Whether that is a thread that you create (e.g., in a direct subclass of `Service`) or whether it is a thread that is provided to you (e.g., in a direct subclass of `IntentService`) varies.

> AsyncTask is associated with an Activity which presumably will stop running if the application is no longer the active application

The primary role of a service is to tell Android that we are doing background work *that should continue for a while, even if the app's UI moves to the background*. That is because Android will terminate your process eventually, to free up system RAM for other apps.

Using a service will tend to keep your process around for a little while longer. An `AsyncTask`, or a bare `Thread`, does not do this. When the app's UI moves to the background, your process is not terminated *immediately*, but it may be terminated *soon*, and so if you want greater assurance that your work will get done, you use a service to manage that work.

Comment: Awesome - thanks just what I needed confirmation on - you should help write the documentation.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald: Sorry. You'll have to settle for [a book](https://commonsware.com/Android). :-)